# Detected trojan on the file packaged by Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have some exe files detected trojan on the file packaged by Inno Setup:

[image]

[image]

These files existed more than 2 years, but were reported trojan file inside by 2~4 vendors at Virustotal.

I used Virustotal to scan all the files before packed by Inno Setup, even Inno Setup itself and found out no problems.

However, after Inno Setup packed, it reported trojan file inside.

Is there anyone with the same problem?

Your comment welcome.

Comment: Very likely a false positive.

Comment: Possibly related to this https://github.com/klamonte/qodem/issues/18 or this https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/183738-inno-setup-xdelta-patch-maker-trojankobter-false-positive/ or this https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=28890.0